# Displaying all townships a lake falls in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, combine

I have a shapefile for lakes, and one for townships. Both are polygon files and all lakes fall inside at least one township and I'm using ArcMap. I'm trying to find a way to quickly and simply generate a table that would list the lakes and then all the townships that lake falls in. 
Ex:

Lake       Townships
Lake1      Township1, Township2, Township3

I unioned the lakes with the townships to get a new file that had the lakes and townships but the records for each lake were broken up, I need a way to get all the townships into that one single field.

Comment: you want a field in the lakes shp file saying which town it is in? you may need two fields if there is more than one town.

Comment: Look into the Spatial Join Tool. In the Field Map dialog you can define the Merge Rule as Join for a Text field. This will combine all Township names that intersect each Lake polygon into a single Field.